# SQL*Plus usability

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm new in Oracle Database studies and I would like to know about the advantages to use SQL*Plus until today? People use it only when they do not have an interface to work or it really has great advantages that we don't find in visual softwares (like PL/SQL, DBeaver, Enterprise Manager, etc.)?

Comment: Please note that this site is for programming questions, like “how do I write this SELECT query” or even “what does the SQL\*Plus DEFINE command do”. Your question, valid as it may be, is out of scope here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two bits to your question: why SQLPlus but also, why use a Command Line Interface?

SQL*Plus was an early command-line interface for Oracle Database. And back in the day, having a terminal and a CLI was as good as it got.

It teaches you to be efficient with the keystrokes. It forces you to memorize commands (and more importantly, patterns). And it gives you a stripped-down, bare bones experience.

Now, when Windows really took off, GUIs became all the rage. A mouse!

So we built GUIs - today we have Enterprise Manager and SQL Developer.

And SQLPlus continued on.

GUIs can make it easier to get started. They can also obscure 'how things work.' They're also heavier, and more involved than a CLI.

There's no right or wrong here - it's about the right tool for the job.

Now.

More than a few years ago, we built a NEW CLI for the Database, it's called Oracle SQLcl. It gives you everything you like about SQLPlus WITH everything you like about SQL Developer.

So, as a new person to Oracle - WELCOME! However, if you're going to be using a cli, use [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html). It's going to be MUCH more user friendly.

Basic Example #1, SQLPlus and query output
[image]

SQLcl and the same query
[image]

Comment: I'm here to help people. Please show me how I'm not honestly trying to help Fernanda.

Comment: From the SO guidelines, "software tools commonly used by programmers;" -- SQLPlus is a tool commonly used by Oracle programmers.

Comment: Now watch the honesty thing. The guidelines also specifically exclude questions asking to compare software packages, and you do know that full well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207361/discussion-between-thatjeffsmith-and-mathguy).

Comment: yes, i'm proud to help people needing help with Oracle technology questions